# What are the glasses that came with this game for?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I just got my copy of Assassin's Creed: Revelations, and stuck to the back of the package is a pair of what appears to be red/blue (actually more like green/magenta) cardboard 3D glasses.  What are these for?  Is the game in 3D?  I don't have a 3D TV, will I be able to use the 3D features of the game?

Comment: You got glasses?  :(  What version of the release?  I have GameStop's "Signature Edition" and doesn't come with such.  Come to think of it, it didn't even come with a game manual...

Comment: I'm not sure what edition precisely, since I didn't order it.  I got it as part of the gaming grant here on Gaming.SE.

Comment: Got this with my grant copy as well; I just assumed it came with everything!

Comment: The Trioviz 3D is actually pretty good. I've only tried it with Batman: Arkham City, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently they were a pre-order bonus from Amazon.com.

According to [this blurb](http://www.astutegamers.com/showthread.php?3570-Assassin-s-Creed-Amazon-Preorder-3D-Glasses):

> Order Assassin's Creed Revelations and receive two Amazon.com
>   exclusives: the Altair outfit single player skin, allowing Ezio to don
>   the wardrobe of his legendary predecessor for the game’s entire
>   campaign, and a pair of TriOviz 3D glasses for Xbox 360 and PS3
>   versions, enabling 3D gameplay on most 2D HDTVs. The code for your
>   outfit will be emailed within two days of your shipment. Offer valid
>   when shipped and sold by Amazon.com. Amazon reserves the right to
>   change or terminate this promotion at any time. Offer will be extended
>   to all existing pre-orders.

Comment: This must be it, closer inspection of the glasses reveals a "TriOviz" logo.  I guess whoever ordered this has an outfit code that goes with this game.

Comment: Now I am curious to know how "3D" this apparent 3D gameplay actually is. :)